# Interop compression

Tags: c#, compression

This is a [function definition](https://github.com/richgel999/lzham_codec/blob/master/include/lzham.h#L196) from an external dll, that I'm calling from my code:

```
LZHAM_DLL_EXPORT lzham_compress_status_t LZHAM_CDECL lzham_compress(
  lzham_compress_state_ptr pState,
  const lzham_uint8 *pIn_buf, size_t *pIn_buf_size,
  lzham_uint8 *pOut_buf, size_t *pOut_buf_size,
  lzham_bool no_more_input_bytes_flag);
```

This function gets an opaque pointer `pState` which is returned from another api call, buffer and size of input block to compress, and buffer and size to write the output to. As the comment have it (reformatted):

```
// Compresses an arbitrarily sized block of data, writing as much available 
// compressed data as possible to the output buffer. 
// This method may be called as many times as needed, but for best perf. try 
// not to call it with tiny buffers.
// pState - Pointer to internal compression state, created by 
// lzham_compress_init.
// pIn_buf, pIn_buf_size - Pointer to input data buffer, and pointer to a 
// size_t containing the number of bytes available in this buffer. 
// On return, *pIn_buf_size will be set to the number of bytes read from the buffer.
// pOut_buf, pOut_buf_size - Pointer to the output data buffer, and a 
// pointer to a size_t containing the max number of bytes that can be 
// written to this buffer.
// On return, *pOut_buf_size will be set to the number of bytes written to this buffer.
// no_more_input_bytes_flag - Set to true to indicate that no more input 
// bytes are available to compress (EOF). Once you call this function with 
// this param set to true, it must stay set to true in all future calls.
```

I would like to know if my code below is overly verbose, and if it can be improved by specifying [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) attributes or in any other way. I'm suspecting that It can be written more idiomatically than my attempt.

```
[DllImport(LzhamDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern unsafe int lzham_compress(IntPtr state, byte* inBuf,
    ref IntPtr inBufSize, byte* outBuf,
    ref IntPtr outBufSize, int noMoreInputBytesFlag);

public static unsafe CompressStatus Compress(IntPtr state, byte[] inBuf, ref 
    int inBufSize, byte[] outBuf, ref int outBufSize, int noMoreInputBytesFlag)
{
    fixed (byte* inBytes = inBuf)
    fixed (byte* outBytes = outBuf)
    {
        IntPtr inSize = new IntPtr(inBufSize);
        IntPtr outSize = new IntPtr(outBufSize);
        CompressStatus result = (CompressStatus)lzham_compress(state, 
            inBytes, ref inSize, outBytes, ref outSize, noMoreInputBytesFlag);
        inBufSize = inBufSize - inSize.ToInt32();
        outBufSize = outBufSize - outSize.ToInt32();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Above, `CompressStatus` is a simple `enum` with all possible return status codes.

Comment: You might want to turn `state` into a `SafeHandle`.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration uses CLR arrays as parameters and does not have unsafe values:

```
[DllImport(LzhamDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern CompressStatus lzham_compress(
    IntPtr state,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)]byte[] inBuf,
    ref uint inBufSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)]byte[] outBuf,
    ref uint outBufSize,
    int noMoreInputBytesFlag);
```

Comment: Hello, please explain why this is better than the OP's code. It'll make for a better review!